# function "fread" causes segmentation error

Tags: c, sizeof, fread

I get a segerror on `fread`; this is very fundamental and yet I am unable to find an answer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void main () 
{
    int i;
    FILE *fp;
    char *re;
    fp = fopen("/net2/192.168.42.151/stud3/2013/dobo1298/data.txt","r");
    i = sizeof(char);
    printf("%d",i);
    re = calloc(10,i);
    fread(re,i,1,fp);
    printf("%s",*re);
}
```

Comment: You don't check whether the earlier call to `fopen` succeeded.  `fread` may segfault if you pass it a `NULL` file pointer.  Once you solve this, you'll also need to null terminate `re` and change your `printf` argument to stop dereferencing `re`

Answer (score 6):

No problem with `fread`. Problem is with `printf` specifier.

```
printf("%s",*re);  
         ^Expects string.
```

but you are passing `char` (`*re`). If you want to use `%s` specifier then pass `re` as argument to `printf`.

Comment: Memory is already allocated for `re` (see the `calloc` line in the question).  If you want to treat it as a string, you'll need to terminate the buffer returned by `fread`

Comment: @simonc; Oh! Missed that.